# How to pass long filename in url and download the file using php function?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a following function that downloads the file whose name is passed as a parameter in the url. Here is the code:

```
    public function actionDownloadFile($filename)
    {
        $file = Yii::app()->request->getBaseUrl(true) . '/upload/digitaluploads/' . $filename; 
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');
        readfile($file);
    }
```

This function is called from view file when the user clicks on download button from the view:

```
<a class="digital-download" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->getBaseUrl('true'); ?>/site/downloadfile/filename/<?php echo urlencode($digital_download['filename']); ?>">Click here to download</a>
```

This works for filename that don't have spaces like it will work for file with the name like `somefile.mp3` but it does not work for the files that have spaces in that. i.e it fails for the files whose name contains spaces like `'maid with the flaxen hair.mp3'`.

As you can see I have even encoded the parameter in the url using urlencode. I tried using decode in action as well but all I get is the broken page.

Anyone?

Comment: use `urlencode()` for spaces

Comment: check whether your file get correct location in the controller and try manually that url in brower if works.

Comment: what you get when you echo `$filename` after retrieve it from url?

Comment: @OnlyMAJ As I already said that this works for the filenames that don't spaces in that. But it does not work for filenames with spaces so it is sure that it is not the path issue

Comment: @Hammad if it doesn't work with space in browser so file doesn't exist.

Comment: @LuisSimioni I get the exact filename without any encode characters. For example if I send urlencode(maid with the flaxen hair.mp3) in the controller I get exactly maid with the flaxen hair.mp3

Comment: @OnlyMAJ Yes I know that, that is why broken page is shown due to spaces in the URL, so I encoded filename with urlencode, so the speaces are replaced by + sign in the url but still download is not initiated

Comment: However if I replace + character with %20 then that works but urlencode encodes spaces to + sign in the url rather than %20. So I read on other question that I should use rawurlencode() to overcome this issue. But rawurlencode does not work either.

Comment: if the only problem is with '+' and '%20' try to use `str_replace('+','%20',$var);` after `urlencode()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this function to avoid space and other possible problems:

```
function fullescape($in) 
{ 
  $out = ''; 
  for ($i=0;$i<strlen($in);$i++) 
  { 
    $hex = dechex(ord($in[$i])); 
    if ($hex=='') 
       $out = $out.urlencode($in[$i]); 
    else 
       $out = $out .'%'.((strlen($hex)==1) ? ('0'.strtoupper($hex)):(strtoupper($hex))); 
  } 
  $out = str_replace('+','%20',$out); 
  $out = str_replace('_','%5F',$out); 
  $out = str_replace('.','%2E',$out); 
  $out = str_replace('-','%2D',$out); 
  return $out; 
}
```

found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
str_replace(' ', '%20', 'your url here');
```

Comment: yes, but its better to rename your files when you wanna upload it on web server to avoid such problems.

Comment: Yes could have been. But my client wants to preserve filenames. Only I can do is to prepend some numbers before filename to keep those unique. Anyways thank you for your answer. I have upvoted

Comment: @Hammad you can save your file name in db as well but rename it when you wanna to upload and when a user wanna download the file you need to pass the stored filename in the header to achieve the goal.

Comment: With this way you are only escaping spaces, you should use urlencode to escape all special characters.